# X get and send keystrokes C++

Tags: c++, linux, keyboard, xorg

I want to make a text replacement program for linux.  ie I type something like .alog, and it gets replaced with /usr/local/apache/logs/.  I know I can do this with alaises, but I am often remotely logged on machines that do not have such alaises.

I am also interested in doing this for learning purposes.

I see some info online about grab and send keystrokes in X for a window I make, but can't find info on doing it for all windows in the workspace.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to start with the code of a window manager as a starting point; Window Managers bind keys to work regardless of window, this is probably a good start. [`dwm`](http://dwm.suckless.org/) is widely held to have beautiful code.

`setup()` appears to add its event mask to the root window directly:

```
    screen = DefaultScreen(dpy);
    root = RootWindow(dpy, screen);
    /* ... */
    /* select for events */
    wa.cursor = cursor[CurNormal];
    wa.event_mask = SubstructureRedirectMask|SubstructureNotifyMask|ButtonPressMask|PointerMotionMask
                    |EnterWindowMask|LeaveWindowMask|StructureNotifyMask|PropertyChangeMask;
    XChangeWindowAttributes(dpy, root, CWEventMask|CWCursor, &wa);
    XSelectInput(dpy, root, wa.event_mask);
    grabkeys();
```